# Fetching values from one dictionary and putting their product into other dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have these two such dictionaries:

> dict1={'C': '0.01464117821', 'E': '0.0621048942', 'D': '0.05465751502', 'G': '0.06693173594', 'F': '0.03875843054', 'I': '0.05478210779', , 'K': '0.05233761138', 'M': '0.02187736464', 'L': '0.09578482304', 'N': '0.04211449136', , 'P': '0.05051274639',  'T': '0.0573250668', , 'V': '0.06446141032', 'Y': '0.02954265733'}
>
> dict2={'CVCVCVCV': ['C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V'], 'FEPFFTTK': ['F', 'E', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'K'],]}

I want a result like:

> dict3={'CVCVCVCV': [value of C from dict1*value of V from dict1..and so on], 'FEPFFTTK': [value of F from dict1*value of E from dict1* value of P from dict1... and so on],]}

Answer (score 0):

```
def product(x):
    a = 1
    for i in x:
        a *= i

    return a

dict1={'A': '0.08449754996', 'C': '0.01464117821', 'E': '0.0621048942', 'D': '0.05465751502', 'G': '0.06693173594', 'F': '0.03875843054', 'I': '0.05478210779', 'H': '0.02252015864', 'K': '0.05233761138', 'M': '0.02187736464', 'L': '0.09578482304', 'N': '0.04211449136', 'Q': '0.040185413', 'P': '0.05051274639', 'S': '0.07603976756', 'R': '0.05819425977', 'T': '0.0573250668', 'W': '0.01273081812', 'V': '0.06446141032', 'Y': '0.02954265733'}

dict2={'CVCVCVCV': ['C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V'], 'FEPFFTTK': ['F', 'E', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'K'], 'SHELRTPL': ['S', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'T', 'P', 'L'], 'DFGTGYS': ['D', 'F', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'Y', 'S'], 'QTNLLALN': ['Q', 'T', 'N', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'N'], 'PNGAGKTT': ['P', 'N', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'K', 'T', 'T']}

for key, values in dict2.items():
    for i in range(len(values)):
        values[i] = float(dict1[values[i]])

dict3 = {}

for key, values in dict2.items():
    dict3[key] = product(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

dict1={'A': '0.08449754996', 'C': '0.01464117821', 'E': '0.0621048942', 'D': '0.05465751502', 'G': '0.06693173594', 'F': '0.03875843054', 'I': '0.05478210779', 'H': '0.02252015864', 'K': '0.05233761138', 'M': '0.02187736464', 'L': '0.09578482304', 'N': '0.04211449136', 'Q': '0.040185413', 'P': '0.05051274639', 'S': '0.07603976756', 'R': '0.05819425977', 'T': '0.0573250668', 'W': '0.01273081812', 'V': '0.06446141032', 'Y': '0.02954265733'}

dict2={'CVCVCVCV': ['C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'V'], 'FEPFFTTK': ['F', 'E', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'K'], 'SHELRTPL': ['S', 'H', 'E', 'L', 'R', 'T', 'P', 'L'], 'DFGTGYS': ['D', 'F', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'Y', 'S'], 'QTNLLALN': ['Q', 'T', 'N', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'N'], 'PNGAGKTT': ['P', 'N', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'K', 'T', 'T']}

for key, values in dict2.items():
    for i in range(len(values)):
        values[i] = float(dict1[values[i]])

dict3 = {}

for key, values in dict2.items():
    dict3[key] = np.product(values)
```